# Custom-made login on Symfony2 (without the gateway)

Tags: php, symfony

What if you want to login an user using a custom form with just username and password fields?

As you know on Symfony2 this login forms are generated by the framework and they POST the information to a gateway that handles everything... I want to POST the credentials to a php script made by my self where i got the POST variables and then create the session (like you do in a framework-less solution)

Please do not make answers/comments about good practices, this is intended as an experiment.

At the moment i have a html form that POST to a php script. And of course a table with username, salt and password created in Symfony. How do i check the credentials and how do I create the session?

Comment: the same way you would outside of symfony... form values are form values... What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Log in forms are not actually generated by the framework.  You make them up yourself: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html.  They are processed by the framework but not generated.

Comment: You want to logging user in php script by creating variable in session?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do this the "right" way requires setting up your own authentication provider.  Which frankly is quite a pain though you will emerge with a good understanding of the security system.

The cookbook can help:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Consider starting by cloning: Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Security\Factory\FormLoginFactory.  Or at least use it as a starting example.

I have not tried this myself but I think you could just provide you own authentiation class by setting a parameter:

```
<parameter key="security.authentication.provider.dao.class">Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider</parameter>
```

If it works then that will be easier then making a complete provider.

And finally you could do what I did the first time and just post to a regular controller and process it all yourself.  You have to hard code the fire wall name but otherwise it's straight forward.  Couple of other threads with the details on how to do this.  The details tend to change a bit with each version of the frame work so looking at the framework class is probably your best bet.  My code is from S2.0 so I won't post it.